# Flutter column child to fill width

Tags: flutter

Supposing you have a column with multiple children, how do you make a child fill the column width?

I know you can set the column's crossAxisAlignment to stretch but I don't want all the children to fill the available width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ConstrainedBox** widget:

```
Column(
  children: [
    ...,
    ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
      child: TheChild()
    )
  ],
)
```

A side note: if you have other children inside a column that need to be positioned different than each other you can use the **Align** widget to align a child to left or right side.